# FileNotFoundError running script from VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Code:

```
def outer(num1):
    print('outer')
    def inner_increment(num1):
        # print('inner')
        return num1 + 1
    # num2 = inner_increment(num1)
    # print(num1, num2)

outer(10)
```

Trace:

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\btk akademi\Pythonda Fonksiyonların İleri Seviye Özellikleri>  & 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\hp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '55707' '--' 'c:\Users\hp\Desktop\btk akademi\Pythonda Fonksiyonların leri Seviye Özellikleri\nesned2.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\hp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\hp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\hp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 237, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\btk akademi\\Pythonda Fonksiyonların leri Seviye Özellikleri\\nesned2.py'    
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\btk akademi\Pythonda Fonksiyonların İleri Seviye Özellikleri>
```

Comment: Looks like you cannot run anything, remove the content an replace it with print("test") and you will probably receive the same error. Your environment is configured incorrectly.

Comment: `No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\btk akademi\\Pythonda Fonksiyonların leri Seviye Özellikleri\\nesned2.py'` Are you sure that's the correct path?

Comment: yes the save path is correct

Comment: Try changing your VS code terminal from Powershell to CMD Prompt. I usually have issues running python scripts from VS code terminal if it's set to Powershell

Comment: how should i do this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.